# Show this set of axioms is $\aleph_0$-categorical.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{\sim\}$ be a FOL and $\Sigma$ the set formed by the following axioms:

- $\left(Ref\right) \;\; \forall x_1 \;\; x_1 \backsim x_1$
- $\left(Sym\right) \;\; \forall x_1 \forall x_2\;\; \left(x_1\backsim x_2\right) \rightarrow \left(x_2\backsim x_1\right)$
- $\left(Trans\right) \;\; \forall x_1\forall x_2\forall x_3 \;\; \left( x_1\backsim x_2 \wedge x_2\backsim x_3 \right) \rightarrow \left( x_1\backsim x_3\right) $
- $\left(EC_n\right)\;\; \exists x_1 \; ... \;\exists x_n \;\; \bigwedge_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \neg \left(x_i \backsim x_j \right)$ for $n=1,2,...$
- $\left(IE_n\right)\;\; \forall x_1\exists x_2 \; ... \;\exists x_{n} \;\; \bigwedge_{1\leq i<j\leq n} x_i \neq x_j \wedge \bigwedge_{i=2}^{n} \left(x_1 \backsim x_i \right)$ para $n=1,2,...$

These axioms are for the sets with an equivalence relation, infinite equivalence classes, each one with infinite elements.

I want to show $\Sigma$ is complete. I already showed it has quantifier elimination and now I want to use Vaught's test for completeness. It is obvious that $\Sigma$ has no finite models and that it does indeed have a model, but I still have to show $\kappa$-categoricity.

I'm kind of wrapped up in this part. I know what I need to prove any two models of cardinal $\aleph_0$ are isomorphic but I'm having trouble defining what that isomorphism should be. I've tried to use representatives of equivalence classes to define it but then I can't prove it is well defined. Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need to go that route?  Unless I'm missing something, since your language doesn't have any nullary functions or relations, quantifier elimination should automatically imply completeness (since the quantifier elimination on a formula with no free variables should give just something like $\top \vee (\bot \wedge \top)$ which would be easy to evaluate).

Comment: @DanielSchepler I actually thought about that, yes, however I was finding it very odd to put it into writing how the formulas would look and explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two countable models $M, N$. Then both $M / \sim_M$ and $N / \sim_N$ are countably infinite, so we have a bijection $f : M / \sim_M \to N / \sim_N$.

Now for each equivalence class $c \in M / \sim_M$, we know that both $c$ and $f(c)$ are countably infinite equivalence classes. So we may pick a bijection $g_c : c \to f(c)$.

Combining all these data, we have a bijection $h : M \to N$ given by $h(x) = g_{[x]}(x)$. In fact, $h$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend stepping back a bit and thinking about classifying **all** models of the theory in question. The key result is the following (the notation I'm using is nonstandard):

> Given a model $M$ of your theory, let $\mathsf{Spec}_M$ be the function sending an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ to the number of classes in $M$ of size $\kappa$. For example, if $M$ consists of countably many equivalence classes each of which has cardinality $\aleph_{17}$, then $$\mathsf{Spec}_M(\kappa)=\begin{cases}
> 0 & \mbox{ if } \kappa\not=\aleph_{17},\\
> \aleph_0 & \mbox{ if }\kappa=\aleph_{17}.
> \end{cases}$$ Show that if $\mathsf{Spec}_M=\mathsf{Spec}_N$ as functions then $M\cong N$.

*HINT: first whip up a bijection between the classes of $M$ and the classes of $N$ which preserves cardinality, then turn that bijection into an isomorphism. Admittedly this is going to involve a lot of arbitrary choices, so "show that there exists" might be more intuitive than "whip up."*

Once you have this result, you'll be done immediately: if $A$ is a countable model of your theory, then each of its classes must have cardinality exactly $\aleph_0$ and there must be exactly $\aleph_0$-many such classes, so we get $$\mathsf{Spec}_A(\kappa)=\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{ if } \kappa\not=\aleph_{0},\\
\aleph_0 & \mbox{ if }\kappa=\aleph_{0}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: If it is enough to define a bijection between the set of equivalence classes, then I think I got it figured out. I was confused with that because I thought the domain of the model would be a set of elements but not the set of the equivalence classes. I don’t know if this question makes sense

Comment: @davinci_07 It is **not enough** to define a bijection between the sets of equivalence classes (and your statement "the domain of the model would be a set of elements but not the set of the equivalence classes" is **correct**). However, defining such a bijection is the **first step** towards getting the isomorphism: basically, we take a bijection $$b: M/\sim_M\rightarrow N/\sim_N$$ and "refine" it into an isomorphism $$\hat{b}: M\rightarrow N.$$ Specifically, we will ensure $\hat{b}(x)\in b([x]_{\sim_M})$.

Comment: (@davinci_07 Sorry, I forgot to include the following in my previous comment: In order for this to work out, of course, we need $b$ to be *more* than just a bijection: it needs to be "size-preserving," in the sense that for each $M$-equivalence class $\alpha$ we need the $N$-equivalence class $b(\alpha)$ to have the same cardinality as $\alpha$ itself.)

Comment: For some reason I can't tag you in my reply but this was of help (also in the sense that I was not sure about that question about set of elements vs set of equivalence classes and you also clarified that for me)!